# Elements not showing up on screen

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The problem that I have is that the WPF xaml code doesn't show up onscreen. What is should do is the following:

- Get list from MainViewModel
- Foreach element it should make a border with a textblock inside

Now it does seem to find the list and all the elements inside it.

Here's the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="MemoryUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MemoryUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Memory" Height="800" Width="900" ResizeMode="NoResize" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainContainer" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3">
            <Grid x:Name="GameGrid">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="6"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border 
                                Background="{Binding Background}" 
                                 Cursor="{Binding Cursor}" 
                                 Margin="{Binding Margin}" 
                                 Height="{Binding Height}" 
                                 Width="{Binding Width}" 
                                 MouseLeftButtonDown="CardClicked">
                                <TextBlock 
                                    Text="{Binding Icon.Text}"                                         
                                    Background="{Binding Icon.Background}" 
                                    Height="{Binding Icon.Height}" 
                                    Width="{Binding Icon.Width}"
                                    Padding="{Binding Icon.Padding}"
                                    FontSize="{Binding Icon.FontSize}"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Icon.Visibility}"
                                    TextAlignment="{Binding Icon.TextAlignment}">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If anymore context or code is needed let me know and I will add it to the post.

Comment: Add ViewModel to the question

Comment: @Pruikhoofd: Where and how are setting the `DataContext` of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following only sets the *design time* `DataContext` that the Visual Studio designer uses:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel}"
```

You must also set the actual `DataContext` property that is used at runtime somewhere. You can either do this in the code-behind of the window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Or in the XAML markup:

```
<Window x:Class="MemoryUI.MainWindow"
        ... d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel}">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainContainer" Orientation="Vertical">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Then your binding to `Cards` should work assuming `Cards` is a public property of the `MainViewModel` class that returns an `IEnumerable`.

The properties of the `Card` class, or whatever you call it, must also be public for your bindings in the `ItemTemplate` to work as expected. You cannot bind to fields.